# Which paypal api to use

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I want to make sure I am using the correct api before investing a bunch of time understanding/learning it. I want to use paypal to allow users of my web application to charge other users.

1. A user (user A) will create a fee;
2. A different user (user B) will pay user A via my web application. There would be many users Bs;
3. The web application is independent of users A and B;
4. The web application would not store the credit card info (hense paypal).

Eventually, I would like to add the ability for user C to create a form and add a fee to the end of the form for user A to pay. user A would then charge user B their portion of the fee charged by user C to user A.

I have not done a lot of homework with the api but I am hoping to use curl and/or php.

Additionally, I have been looking at stripe. It seems like a far more simple api but has limited capabilities.

Comment: This is not a research or resource recommendation site. Do your homework on the matter before coming to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use Adaptive Payment. However Adaptive Payment in PayPal is open to a selected merchant. If you wish to use that, I suggest you to file a ticket to their MTS and they will assist you further on this.

Contact them [here](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ5NDk5NDE5OS9zaWQvZlVzdmhBeGRrRzJwdVVaZjhta1ZYNEo3TG52ZU1zOElSYUxqNU9ESk1SUlZlX3NiOWFQWU5Jck9yaTZrSk9GQ3k0NWtlWXh5bjY1dEpxVDlXQUVEZXNLWjVfOTZwdHdrcjgyVUVubW85T0pTR09sbU5qYnB3UUNnJTIxJTIx).